# i want to install an APK file via adb commands using tcpip or the wifi not via usb

Tags: android, tcp, adb, usb-debugging

i want to install an apk file via adb command using wirless option tcpip not via usb , and it's not wokring  i get this [i get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLSrq.jpg)   the command i used is " adb install name.apk " note i have android 10, have already enabled usb debugging and install via usb and all that , please help thank you

i tried to install an apk file via adb command on wifi network tcpip and i expected it to be installed on my phone

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are installing an apk that does not have native library files **(*.so files found in the lib/arm** folder in the apk file)** for your specific device. You must have downloaded the wrong apk file which might be supported for **x86(intel processors)** but your phone is **arm 64bit or arm 32bit**. Please cross check the device model for architecture and download the correct apk and the installation using the same command will be successful.

please comment down your phone model if you need any assistance.

> Its not a problem that occurred when you use adb over network. You
> should also get the error through USB as well.

Comment: i tried now to download another APK and it worked , thank you sir for your time my model is infinix x657B

Comment: Appreciate your reply and am glad the problem is fixed.